# asp.net mvc associate resource files for display templates based on location of ascx file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization

I'm trying to minimise the amount of repeated code in my project. A lot of the views we have summarise data from our viewmodels. the viewmodels abstract some quite modular data. When displaying this stuff the structure of the modular stuff is always the same, the text however changes depending on which view is hosting the display template. So...

in section1 i might have:

```
public class Section1ReportViewModel{
    [UiHint("Person")]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Section1), Name="ReportedPerson")]
    public Person  ReportedPerson {get; set; } 

    [UiHint("Address")]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Section1), Name="HomeAddress")]
    public Address HomeAddress {get; set; }

    [UiHint("Person")]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Section1), Name="AssociatedPerson")]
    public Person  AssociatedPerson {get; set; } 
}
```

the report view in Views/Section1/index.aspx would might then have:

```
@Model Section1ReportViewModel

@Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.ReportedPerson)
@Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.HomeAddress)
@Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.AssociatedPerson)
```

Mvc can look in the Shared/DisplayTemplates folder to retrieve the display templates using the UiHint attribute.

Now, so that i don't go re-creating all the views and stuff, in section 2 i would have:

```
public class Section2ReportViewModel{
    [UiHint("Person")]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Section2), Name="ReportedPerson")]
    public Person  ReportedPerson {get; set; } 

    [UiHint("Address")]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Section2), Name="HomeAddress")]
    public Address HomeAddress {get; set; }

    [UiHint("Person")]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Section2), Name="AssociatedPerson")]
    public Person  AssociatedPerson {get; set; } 
}
```

and the view in Views/Section2/index.aspx

```
@Model Section1ReportViewModel

@Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.ReportedPerson)
@Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.HomeAddress)
@Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.AssociatedPerson)
```

And as an example of one of the display templates (Person.ascx):

```
@Model Person 
<h1>@Html.Resource("Title")</h1>
<dl>
    @Html.DetailLineFor(x=>x.FullName)
    @Html.DetailLineFor(x=>x.DateOfBirth)
</dl>
```

Now... here's the puzzle. I want to keep these shared views in the Shared/DisplayTemplates folder. But I don't want to keep the resource files for them in the Shared/DisplayTemplates/App_LocalResources folder. I want to keep the resource file in Views/Section2/DisplayTemplates/App_LocalResources/Person.ascx.resx

The reason is so that the text for the h1 tag will be specific to Section2 and when the same template is used in section 1 the text from Views/Section1/DisplayTemplates/App_LocalResources/Person.ascx.resx will be used.

Is there any way to get this working? I had it in my head that the search paths for this stuff would be able to handle it, but apparently not :(

Answer (score 0):

Not finding it easy to create an Html helper as the ctx passed in is that of the template, and it has no idea of the parent view. Faking the Url is not possible to pass to the GetLocalResourceObject for 2 reasons:

1 if you're using areas, the templates context lies about its virtual url and physical url.

2: you cannot new up a ResourceExpressionBuilder and call ParseExpression on the resource expression using a "fake" url to try and trick the system into thinking the template comes from the folder containing the App_LocalResources holding the required resx.

Gutted!!

As another hack i am going to try adding the templates into the folders using linked items. I'll report back with my findings.